# PHP doesn't receive ajax post data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have been struggling with it for a week...I want to use Ajax in datatables to pass some parameters to my PHP file for server side searching. But it seems my PHP file got nothing. But the datatable works just fine and the table can return from sever side processing and display on the html page correctly. However, var_dump( $_POST['species']) returns null.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(species);
    $("#table").DataTable({
      "destroy": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "processing": true,
      "paging": false,
      "searching": false,

      columns: [{
          data: "d"
        },
        {
          data: "c"
        },
        {
          data: "p"
        }
      ],
      ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          "species": s
        },
        url: "./php/search_test.php"
      }

    });
  });
```

```html
<div class="container text-center" id="tablecontainer" name="tablecontainer">
  <table id="table" class="display nowrap row-border strip p-2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <center>d</center>
        </th>
        <th>
          <center>C</center>
        </th>
        <th>
          <center>P</center>
        </th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

'''php

```
ini_set ('memory_limit',  '2048M');
$sql_details = array(
'host' => 'localhost',
'user' => 'root',
'pass' => '',
'db'   => 'xxxxx'
);

// DB table to use
$table = 'h';
```

//if I try this here: $s=$_POST["s"]; echo $s;It
//returns: Warning: Undefined array key "s".

```
// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'd';

// column
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'd', 'dt' => 'd' ),
array( 'db' => 'c', 'dt' => 'c' ),
array( 'db' => 'p',  'dt' => 'p' ),


);

// Include SQL query processing class
require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
SSP::complex( $_POST, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey,$columns)
);
```

```
Could someone help me with it? Thanks.
```

Comment: check the browser developer tools network tab to see what is being actually posted to PHP ... since your code does not show what `species` even is (no declaration at all), it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong - it's also interesting to note that the PHP you posted make no reference to `species` anyway, so, not sure what you think anyone could do for you with the absolute lack of information regarding your so called issue

Comment: Sorry I didn't make the question clear. I am new to stackflow and  also programming. I will edit my question to make it clear.

Comment: Is `species` declared before you try to use it in `{"species":species}`?

Comment: I am sorry somehow I cannot eidt my question. Yes. I declared species in other parts of the code but it's too long so I didn't copy it here. If I console typeof('species'), it shows it is a string.

Comment: Click on the [Edit] link to edit your question. You can find it at the bottom of the question, underneath the question's tags (see `Share  Edit  Close  Delete`)

Comment: your edit did nothing to clarify the questions I asked of you @JieJiang

Comment: Sorry i modified it. The system didn't allow me to do so yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Replace **$_POST** to **$array**

> $array = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
> print_r($array);

Comment: I tried this but nothig returned.